# How do I pass an extra variable to a a datatemplate

Tags: wpf

I have a DataTemplate(well two data templates) that I want to use as views for some
basic form viewmodels(that that contain a value and and boolean indicating whether I want to use the value).

I want to use the datatemplate(s) several times for separate form items. I think the right way to do this is to set it as the ContentControl's ContentTemplate (in that case it will have the same data context right?) but I also want to pass the label string and since the label string is part of the ui and doesn't change it seems wrong to put it in the viewmodel object. How do I give access of the label string to the DataTemplate instance?

Comment: Your question in unclear. What do you mean by *"pass it the string to use in the form UI"*?

Comment: The form ui consists of a label a textbox and a checkbox, the checkbox and textbox are bound to properties of the data context.

Comment: But I think the label specifying the human readable text of the label above the textbox should not be part of the datacontext object.

Comment: So why not instead of only creating a ContentControl, Create 2 controls (in a grid for instance): A Label with the text specific for each form ***and*** the ContentControl which has the DataTemplate?

Comment: Because it seems wrong, I'm trying to abstract the element, is there no easy way to give pass individual data to the DataTemplate other then the binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like its name, a `DataTemplate` is used to template the *Data*... For example, if you have a class called `MyItem` which has a `Name` and `Value` and you want this shown in a specific way, you'll set a datatemplate for Item and use it whenever needed.

In your case, you're speaking about having very similar `views`, with only a minor change between them. This minor change (if I understood your question correctly) is not something that comes from the model or from the viewmodel but something which is entirely view-oriented (a different title for the page, for instance).

If you plan on using a different viewmodel for every view, and each viewmodel has a different purpose - I don't see a problem with adding a `Title` property to the VM and bind to that too (Remember, MVVM is a set of guidelines, not rules...)

If you still rather have it separated from the viewmodel, then you can use an **[Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx)**. Create an Attached Property called `TemplateTitle`, for instance, and have each contentcontrol in each view change it. The label, of course, will bind to that Attached Property.